# parsing xml having multiple namespaces using xml::Libxml::Xpathcontext in perl

Tags: perl, xpath, xml-libxml

I have to parse following XML:

```
<reply xmlns="urn::ietf::param" xmlns:element="https://xml.example.net/abc/12.3"
message-id='1'>
<abc>
<xyz> hello </xyz>
</abc>
</reply>
```

I want the value of xyz node i.e. hello, but findnodes is returning null value.
my code is :

```
 my $xpath=XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($dom);
    $xpath->registerNs('ns1','urn::ietf::param'); 
    $xpath->registerNs('ns2','https://xml.example.net/abc/12.3');
    $val=$xpath->findnodes('//ns1:reply/ns2:element/abc/xyz'); 
    print $val;
```

but print statement is returning null value

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have some misunderstanding about how namespaces work. `xmlns:element="https://xml.example.net/abc/12.3"` means that there is a prefix `element` defined  with this specific namespace URI. This namespace is actually never used in your XML.

`xmlns="urn::ietf::param"` defines a default namespaces and also applies to all descendant elements.
And actually you have no `<element/>` element in your XML.

Thus, the following XPath should work as expected:

```
//ns1:reply/ns1:abc/ns1:xyz
```